# Using AWS S3 Java client to obtain directory and object metadata

Tags: scala, amazon-s3, java-client

Scala 2.11 here, although this concerns the [AWS S3 Java client API](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/) so it's really a Java question. It would be *awesome* if someone can provide an answer in Scala, but I'll *happily* accept any Java answer that works (I can always Scala-ify it on my own time).

---

I am trying to use the AWS S3 client library to connect to a bucket on S3 which was the following directory structure underneath it:

```
my-bucket/
    3dj439fj9fj49j/
        data.json
    3eidi04d40d40d/
        data.json
    a874739sjsww93/
        data.json
    ...
```

Hence every immediate child object under the bucket is a directory with an alphanumeric name. I'll call these the "ID directories". And each of these ID directories all have a single child object that are **all** named `data.json`.

I need to accomplish several things:

1. I need an array/map/datastruct of strings (Java `Array<String>` or Scala `Array[String]`) containing all the alphanumeric IDs of the ID directories (so element 0 is `"3dj439fj9fj49j"`, element 1 is `"3eidi04d40d40d"`, etc.); and
2. I need an array/map/datastruct of dates (Java `Array<Date>` or Scala `Array[Date]`) containing the *Last Modified* timestamp of each ID directory's corresponding `data.json` file. So if `mybucket/3dj439fj9fj49j/data.json` had a Last Modified date/timestamp of, say, **2017-05-29 11:19:24T**, then that datetime would be the first element of this second array
3. These two arrays/maps/datastructs need to be associative, meaning I could access, say, the 4th element of the first (ID) array and get the 5th ID directory underneath `my-bucket`, and I could also access the 4th element of the second (date) array and get the Last Modified timestamp of the 5th ID directory's `data.json` child object

These don't **necessarily** have to be arrays, they could be maps, tuples, whatever. I just need 1+ data structures to hold this content as described above.

From the [lib's Javadocs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/ObjectMetadata.html#getLastModified--) I see an `ObjectMetadata#getLastModified` field, but I don't see anything for reading parent directory paths for a given `S3Object` (meaning the `data.json`'s parent ID directory). All in all, my best attempt is failing pretty spectacularly:

```
val s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey))
val bucketRoot : S3Object = s3Client.getObject("myBucket","/")

// TODO: How to query 'bucketRoot' for all its child ID directories?
val idDirs : Array[S3Object] = ???

var dataMap : Map[String,Date] = null
idDirs.foreach(idDir ->
  // TODO: getName() and getChildSomehow() don't exist...obviously
  dataMap :+ idDir.getName() -> idDir.getChildSomehow("data.json").getObjectMetadata.getLastModified
)
```

**Any S3 API gurus out there that can spot where I'm going awry, or nudge me in the right direction here?** Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think, you are looking for `listObjects`. 
First, read the javadoc for `ListObjectRequest`. If something remains unclear, update your post with a more specific question.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/ListObjectsRequest.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call [`AmazonS3#listObjects(String)`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3.html#listObjects-java.lang.String-) to get a list of objects in the bucket.  The response will contain an [`S3ObjectSummary`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/S3ObjectSummary.html) for each key found.  You can call [`S3ObjectSummary#getLastModified()`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/S3ObjectSummary.html#getLastModified--) to get the last modified date/time.

Here is an example that ties it all together with some Scala code.

### Input from S3 Bucket

```
> aws s3 ls --recursive s3://<REDACTED>/
2017-08-02 13:45:12          0 3dj439fj9fj49j/
2017-08-02 13:45:28          0 3dj439fj9fj49j/data.json
2017-08-02 13:45:16          0 3eidi04d40d40d/
2017-08-02 13:45:33          0 3eidi04d40d40d/data.json
2017-08-02 13:45:19          0 a874739sjsww93/
2017-08-02 13:45:37          0 a874739sjsww93/data.json
```

### Code

```
import collection.JavaConverters._

import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSStaticCredentialsProvider
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder

val key = <REDACTED>
val secret = <REDACTED>
val bucketName = <REDACTED>
val region = <REDACTED>

val creds = new BasicAWSCredentials(key, secret)
val s3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard.withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(creds)).withRegion(region).build

val objectSummaries = s3.listObjects(bucketName).getObjectSummaries.asScala
val dataFiles = objectSummaries.filter { _.getKey.endsWith("data.json") }
val dataDirectories = dataFiles.map(dataFile => {
  val keyComponents = dataFile.getKey.split("/")
  val parent = if (keyComponents.length > 1) keyComponents(keyComponents.length - 2) else "/"
  (parent, dataFile.getLastModified)
})
dataDirectories.foreach(println)
```

### Output

```
(3dj439fj9fj49j,Wed Aug 02 13:45:28 PDT 2017)
(3eidi04d40d40d,Wed Aug 02 13:45:33 PDT 2017)
(a874739sjsww93,Wed Aug 02 13:45:37 PDT 2017)
```

### Explanation

First, we have some bootstrapping to set up credentials and create the client.  Then, we issue `listObjects`, which triggers a call to the S3 service.  We `filter` those results to only keys ending with "data.json".  Then, we `map` the results to tuples consisting of the parent path name and the object's last modified date/time.  To determine the parent path, we `split` on the path separator and retrieve the previous path component.  As a special case, if the file is in the root directory, then we say that its parent is `"/"`.

I chose to represent the results as tuples, but you can change this to some other data structure if you prefer.

Note that for buckets containing a very large number of objects, you might want to use [`AmazonS3#listObjects(String, String)`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3.html#listObjects-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) instead, so that you can restrict the results returned to keys matching a specific prefix.  This will cut down the amount of network bandwidth consumed by the response and the amount of processing required on the response data.

For even more options, you could also consider [`AmazonS3#listObjects(ListObjectsRequest)`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3.html#listObjects-com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ListObjectsRequest-) or [`AmazonS3#listObjectsV2(ListObjectsV2Request)`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3.html#listObjectsV2-com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ListObjectsV2Request-).